# HTML code generates syntax error but still works; "correct" code doesn't

Tags: html, image, embedding

A friend (and like me, HTML novice) shared this bit of code for embedding a live video stream from a camera on a web page:

```
<iframe scrolling="no" width="640" height="480"
<img src = http://10.0.0.172:8086/stream_simple.html"
stream=BoardOne" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen>
</iframe>
```

This seems obviously wrong to me (and never mind the missing open quotes before the URL and "BoardOne"). In fact, PHPStorm flags a "Tag start is not closed" error right after the "480". The unclosed `img` tag plopped right in the middle of the `iframe` attributes can't work, can it?

And yet my friend tells me it does. Worse, when I try to correct it to what seems right to me, he tells me it doesn't work. Here's my version:

```
<iframe scrolling="no" width="640" height="480"
stream="BoardOne" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen>
    <img src="http://10.0.0.172:8086/stream_simple.html"/>
</iframe>
```

Again, I'm a novice: can someone explain how my friend's code can work and yet he claims mine doesn't?

Answer (score 1):

It "works" depending on what your definition of "works" is.

An iframe is supposed to have a `src` attribute, and the content of that URL will be rendered into the `<iframe>` element. The content of an `<iframe>` element is only fallback content that appears if the browser doesn't understand what an `<iframe>` is.

In the first case, the HTML is pretty much garbage, so you're depending on how the browser will actually leniently interpret it. It looks like it's largely ignoring the partial `<img` tag in there and associates the `src` attribute with the `iframe`, so it has that attribute and displays the content.

In the second, syntactically correct case, the `<iframe>` is correctly understood to be an iframe and the `<img>` to be its fallback content, so it doesn't show up, because your browser understands iframes. And you have moved the `src` attribute to be an attribute of the `<img>`, so the iframe is missing a `src` and doesn't display anything.

Comment: Given that the source for this `iframe` is supposed to be a live video feed from a camera, what should the code be?

Comment: Probably the `<img` is simply superfluous and ended up there as a typo: `<iframe scrolling="no" width="640" height="480" src="http://10.0.0.172:8086/stream_simple.html"
stream="BoardOne" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>`

Comment: Actually, in the first block it does have a source, because the `iframe` tag isn't properly closed <img becomes an attribute of the `iframe` and then what would be the image's source is actually the iframe's source.

Comment: @Knight Yes, as I said. :o)

Comment: @deceze didn't see your comment while I was typing.

Comment: BTW I can't find anything about an HTML attribute `stream`. Is it bogus? I assume it's ignored if the browser doesn't recognize it. If it exists, what's it for? Also, is it possible that a `video` element might be better than an `iframe` for this?

Answer (score 0):

Your code definitely works. Your friends code doesn't work. There is no way unclosed tag won't cause a syntax error

Answer (score 0):

The first code example is obviously wrong. You can check HTML validation using a tool like the [w3c markup validation tool](https://validator.w3.org/#validate_by_input). Try going to the tool typing in

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head><title></title></head>
<body>
<iframe scrolling="no" width="640" height="480"
stream="BoardOne" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen>
    <img src="http://10.0.0.172:8086/stream_simple.html"/>
</iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

and read the error messages about the iframe tag.

Also if you are new to HTML and you are relying on your friend to tell you if your code works you should really learn how to test it on your own computer, (in most cases you can just create a plain text file ending in .html extension and open it in a browser), or use an online tool like [codepen](https://codepen.io/) or [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/) to test your code.